# How to format (Bold) PivotTable.PivotFields(i)? VBA, PivotTable Objects

Tags: excel, vba, format, pivot-table

Thank you for taking the time to read my inquiry.

I am using Pivot Table Objects. I want to format, in the table seen below, the **Class1 and Class2 entire rows** (**, table reference) using VBA.

I understand that I can use:

```
s = DataRange/LabelRange, with PivotTable(n).PivotFields(m).s
```

Is there a way I can select just the cells that I need?

```
                Sum of x  Sum of y  Sum of z
**Class1             C1.X     C1.Y      C1.Z**
   String.C1.1     x         y         z
   String.C1.2     x         y         z
   String.C1.3     x         y         z
**Class2             C1.X     C1.Y      C1.Z**
   String.C2.1     x         y         z
   String.C2.2     x         y         z
   String.C2.3     x         y         z
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!:

1. Create a PivotTable style named "what_ever" and edit the corresponding "Row Subheading (i)`"
2. In the VBA code just assign the style with `PivotTable(i).TableStyle2 = "what_ever"`

This was far easier than I tought and I lost so much time